# using callAsyncJavaScript in WKWebView

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview

What difference between methods `callAsyncJavaScript` and `evaluateJavaScript`?
Using it with same script like:

```
evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()")
```

and

```
callAsyncJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()")
```

returns different results:
HTML in first, and .sucess(nil) in second...

Comment: And if I click the button on webpage in my script when completionHandler will be called? When I did click OR when page will be reloaded after that click?

Comment: If there is a function named ```myJavascriptFunction```, passing this function name as string in callAsync function will execute this function. While passing the same in evaluate may return you function body. When i say passing, i mean without round brackets, just the function name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 3 methods that allow to run JS from WKWebView (well, there's more signatures, but 3 principle methods):

- The oldest and most primitive is [`evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript), which allows to run arbitrary piece of code. This day and age, there's no excuse to use, as it has no benefits over the other methods.
- The more modern improved version is [`evaluateJavaScript(_:in:in:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3656442-evaluatejavascript) which was introduced in iOS 14. It can be used to run synchronous code. It uses a modern way to present a result - `Result<Any, Error>`, which allows to encapsulate any sort of result, success or failure in a single convenient to use object. But the key difference is that it allows you to specify [the context of the script](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkcontentworld), which prevents conflicts between different scripts:

> Executing a script in its own content world effectively gives it a separate copy of the environment variables to modify.

- But neither of these functions is able to support asynchronous JavaScript code, i.e. [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You *can* implement promise execution if you combine `evaluateJavaScript` with `WKScriptMessage` (e.g. as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65291276/in-ios-13-and-below-how-can-wkwebview-call-an-async-javascript-function-i-e-o)), but it's very awkward. So [`callAsyncJavaScript(_:arguments:in:in:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3656441-callasyncjavascript) solves that problem: you can use it to execute a Promise, without additional help of `WKScriptMessage`, which makes code less distributed, and easier. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68169869/5318223) an example of how it's done.

It also has 2 additional advantages of this method:

- The first argument is no longer a function name, but `functionBody`, which becomes an anonymous function, and prevents the naming conflicts possible due to global scope of the function.
- And also arguments are separated from the body as `[String : Any]`, which allow us to define function body somewhere statically, and reuse it by passing the arguments (as opposed to injecting them to function body as you need with `evaluateJavaScript`.

So you *should* be using this method for executing asynchronous JS code, and you *can* use it for the synchronous code.

One more thing: with `callAsyncJavaScript` you need to remember that you are defining the function *body*, so if you want something returned, you need to use the word `return` (as opposed to `evaluateJavaScript`, where you defined a piece of code to run, which can have no `return`, unless you define a function).

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude. Such detailed, descriptive answer, I’m impressed. 